# how can i get req.header in route array

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

My handler Code

```
const handler = createStaticHandler(routes);
app.get("*", async (req, res) => {
  const headers = req.headers;
  const fetchRequest = createFetchRequest(req);
  const context = await handler.query(fetchRequest);
  const router = createStaticRouter(handler.dataRoutes, context);
  const text = renderToString(
    <Provider store={Store}>
      <StaticRouterProvider router={router} context={context} />
    </Provider>
  );
```

My Route definition

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    Component: App,
    loader: async ({ request }) => {
      return await fetch("http://localhost:3000/v1/api/auth/getme");
    },
]
```

please help me how can i get req.header in fetch function. whenever i load my app this does not sending header with cookies to backend.

Comment: Are you trying to access req.header? It should be req.headers and if not i am not getting your question, please explain in detail